# i want to click a link of website using scrapy python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://ozhat-turkiye.com/en/brands/a',
    ]
```

> I want to click a link

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.drivers = webdriver.Firefox('C:/Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox')
```

> I want to click a link

```
def parse(self, response):
    for title in response.css('div.tabledivinlineblock a.tablelink50::attr(href)').extract():
        yield {'title': title,
               'response': response.url
               }

   # i want to click this a tag
    next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="maincontent_DataPager"]/a[last()]')

    # follow pagination links
    # for href in response.css('span#maincontent_DataPager a:last-child'):
    #
    #     yield response.follow(href, self.parse)

    next_page = response.css('span#maincontent_DataPager a:last-child::attr(href)').extract_first().strip()
    if next_page is not None:
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: We can best help you if you describe where your script is failing, and the specific exception message you get when it fails.  Also, please correct the formatting of your question...text and code is confused as I see it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should fetch you the required items exhausting all the clicks connected to next page link. You can't use here `response.follow()` as there is no link to follow other than clicking on it.

```
import time
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://ozhat-turkiye.com/en/brands/a',
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            for title in self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.tabledivinlineblock a.tablelink50'):
                yield {'title': title.text,'response': response.url}

            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span#maincontent_DataPager a:last-child').click()
            except Exception: break
```

I used harcoded wait within the script which is not recommended at all. You should replace the same with `Explicit Wait`.

Comment: the purpose is to call a javascript function basically my pagination elements click load data of next page and i want to load the elements through next button just tell me how to call a javascript function because my href has a javascript function and i don't know how to call it.

Comment: Check out the title of your post. However, the above script also populates the next page content by clicking on the next page button.

Comment: this is working fine but i don't want to open page on browser i just want to update the response so that i can scrap data from it please help

Comment: Then make it headless by using chrome option. If you did not want to use any browser simulator then your post becomes confusing as you have already initiated it within your above script. Thanks.

Comment: i know you are tell me what i want but sir i want to go inside the each link which is getting here by ur script i just want to ask how i move to nested page.